# mySQL: get values from multiple lines with all wheres

Tags: php, mysql, select, distinct

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `left_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `right_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `left_id`, `right_id`) VALUES (2, 111, 90),
   (3, 111, 91),(4, 111, 92),(5, 111, 93),(6, 111, 94),(7, 111, 95),
   (8, 222, 90),(9, 222, 91),(10, 222, 92),(11, 222, 93),(12, 222, 94),
   (13, 222, 95),(14, 333, 90),(15, 333, 91),(16, 333, 92),(17, 333, 93),
   (18, 333,94),(19, 333, 100);
```

which looks like

```
id | left_id | right_id 
2  | 111     | 90
3  | 111     | 91
4  | 111     | 92
5  | 111     | 93
6  | 111     | 94
7  | 111     | 95

8  | 222     | 90
9  | 222     | 91
10 | 222     | 92
11 | 222     | 93
12 | 222     | 94
13 | 222     | 95

14 | 333     | 90
15 | 333     | 91
16 | 333     | 92
17 | 333     | 93
18 | 333     | 94
19 | 333     | 100
```

`left_id` is a record of a "news" and `right_id` records the categories that the news record belongs to.

Now I want all left_ids (distinct) that have EXACTLY/ALL right_ids 90 & (91 OR 92) & 93 & 94 & 95

In long sentence:
Give me (distinct) the `left_id`, where `right_id` is

```
(90 & 91 & 93 & 94 & 95)
OR
(90 & 92 & 93 & 94 & 95)
```

The result must be `111` and `222`; not `333`, because `333` has `NOT 95`.

Comment: a lot of useless tries ;)
have no idea. maybe union or multiple joins to "itself" could solve my problem. just "where right_id IN ()" or similar is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` together with `REGEXP` for that in order to match exact values:

```
SELECT
    left_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT right_id ORDER BY right_id) gc
FROM
    test
GROUP BY
    left_id
HAVING
    gc REGEXP '90.+(91|92).+(93).+(94).+(95)'
```

Output is:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| left_id | gc                |
+---------+-------------------+
|     111 | 90,91,92,93,94,95 |
|     222 | 90,91,92,93,94,95 |
+---------+-------------------+
2 rows in set
```

Comment: Looks fine, but should be a regexp to handle "91 OR 92 OR 91,92"

Comment: Yeah, that ain't the output.

Comment: ((91|92).+)+ would be implicit OR, 91 AND/OR 92. Does MySql also take `((91|92).+){1,2}`? But that would require unique key on (left_id,right_id).

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, yes, as OP wants - implicit  91 OR 92. That includes 91 AND 92.

Comment: Therefore regex should allow one or more occurrences. `((91|92).+)+` ;-)

Comment: okay this solution looks very promising.
but two questions:
- what about performance on a large table with >2.000.000 rows?
- what if the OR-clause is not 91|92, but 91|95? i guess the ORDER will fail :-/

Comment: @Ridgeback Why not suck it and see?

Comment: if 91|95 instead of 91|92, the regexp (91|95) will only find one line, the one with 91 at this point. this is because the 95 is right of 94, not right of 91. this is because of the "order by".
`REGEXP '90.+(91|95).+(92).+(93).+(94)'`

hmmmmm or maybe the sequence does not matter?

Comment: @Ridgeback, each and every answer here is based on your input. However you can play easily with REGEXP in order to achieve any other output.

Comment: hm okay i played with it. your solution works only if the OR-ids are close to each other. the idea with sorted group_concat is great in combination with the regex, but i see some problems with multiple-ORs. but i learned a lot with your suggestion, thanks for that mitkosoft :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this query is independent of any ordering in id's and any possible duplicate entries:

```
SELECT  left_id
FROM    `test`
WHERE   right_id IN (90,91,93,94,95)
GROUP BY left_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT right_id) = 5
UNION 
SELECT  left_id
FROM    `test`
WHERE   right_id IN (90,92,93,94,95)
GROUP BY left_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT right_id) = 5
```

Comment: Looks as current version depends on *unique key on (left_id, right_id)* what in fact could be recommendable, but isn't done yet in the CREATE statement of the question.

Comment: The GROUP BY left_id and DISTINCT right_id make it unique.

Comment: Right, not seen the lower case "distinct".

Comment: Updated to uppercase ;)

Comment: I suspect(/hope) that left/right combinations are defined as UNIQUE, rendering the DISTINCT obsolete.

Comment: @Strawberry As you can see, it isn't yet, but the OP should be encouraged to do so.

Comment: well now i´m on this solution.
at this time i see no problems caused by group_concat and no complicated joins. just unions.

With ONE or (91|92) i have 2 selects with 1 union.
With TWO or (91|92) and (93|94) i need 4 selects and 3 unions.
With THREE ... and so on. 
Could be a lot of text, but easily to generate in PHP - and i guess performance should be okay.

i´ll figure out

---- btw: left and right combination is unique, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the property of group_concat and check if the result is the same of the string you provided ..

```
select distinct left_id, group_concat(right_id) from test 
having group_concat(right_id) = ('90,91,93,94,95')
   or group_concat(right_id) = ('90,92,93,94,95') 
group_by left_id
```

eventually adapt the format of string to the formatted resul fo group_concat

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* -- [OR DISTINCT a.left_id] 
  FROM test a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.left_id 
         FROM test x 
        WHERE x.right_id IN(90,93,94,95) 
        GROUP 
           BY x.left_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
     ) b
    ON b.left_id = a.left_id
 WHERE a.right_id IN (91,92);
```

Comment: Now your´s :)
it´s faster then the regex-solution and looks scalable for multiple-ORs.
I´ll try, gimme some minutes to figure out

Comment: Okay, i´m done. The weak spot of this solution is, it will work only with one OR-clause. If i try to have two ORs like 91|92 and 93|94, i have to make a join in the join. could work, but probably a lot of code and difficult to understand.

Comment: Yeah, I can only really answer the question that's asked. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select left_id, group_concat(right_id) value
from test 
group by 1
having value = ('90,91,93,94,95')
   or value = ('90,92,93,94,95')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit mask. You find the *position p* in a set, shift the value `1` *p times* left and once right. 1st position results in binary 0001, 2nd in 0010, 3rd in 0100 aso. Aggregate this by binary OR.

Now you can easily build conditions. `mask = mask & aggregate` means every bit set in mask is also set in aggregate. `mask & aggregate` means at least one bit of the mask is set in aggregate.

```
SELECT
  `left_id`,                        # 1  2  4  8  16 32
   BIT_OR(1<<FIND_IN_SET(`right_id`, '90,91,92,93,94,95')>>1) `right_or`
FROM
  `ids`
GROUP BY
  `left_id`
HAVING   1|8|16|32 = (1|8|16|32) & `right_or`
   AND   (2|4) & `right_or`
;
```

same with condition 91 or 95:

```
SELECT
  `left_id`,
  BIT_OR(1<<FIND_IN_SET(`right_id`, '90,91,92,93,94,95')>>1) `right_or`
FROM
  `ids`
GROUP BY
  `left_id`
HAVING    1|4|8|16 = (1|4|8|16) & `right_or`
   AND    (2|32) & `right_or`
;
```

Of course you can precalculate constants, e.g. 1|4|8|16 = 29. I wanted to show a readable example.